# Can't locate element by id

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am doing this:

```
WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
```

but I get:

```
Unable to locate element: #username
```

My DOM looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="u-leader-m10"
required="required" tabindex="1">
```

From the looks of it, everything is alright. So, what are some areas to investigate this failure?
Happy to provide more info. I just don't know what can be relevant.

Edit: I've tried 'name' instead of 'id' and it's working - still confused!

Comment: 1) check if you are trying to get the element before page loading is completed (if yes then use WebDriverWait with ExpectedConditions) 2) check if the username is present in the iframe (if yes, then make sure to switch to frame before trying to access the element)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below one

```
WebElement userName = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("username")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I don't see any issue with your code block using the `id` attribute, however the optimum strategy to locate elements within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) will depend a lot on the type of the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) and your desired actions on the elements.

Having said that, it seems the element is a `<input>` element and moving forward either you would invoke `click()` or `sendKeys()` and to achieve that you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement userName = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#username[name='username']")));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement userName = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='username' and @name='username']")));
  ```